# Android: ListPreference setDefaultValue()

Tags: android

Why its not work in Code ? in XML its ok, but not in Code.

```
String [] testValues = {"a" , "b", "c"};
ListPreference test = (ListPreference)findPreference(KEY);
test.setEntries(testValues);
test.setEntryValues(testValues);
test.setDefaultValue(testValue[0]);
```

Comment: I'm talking about setDefaultValue....In XML its ok, but here in code its not...Why ?

Comment: This just in - you can accept answers by clicking the little check mark next to the answer given to one of your questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197228/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-listpreference/17509197#17509197

Could you see please, here is my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to set the Default Value of a ListPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197228/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-listpreference)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try `test.setValueIndex(0);`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `setDefaultValue` on `ListPreference`, you may use `setValue` to change the value. The complete code would be:

```
String [] testValues = {"a" , "b", "c"};
ListPreference test = (ListPreference)findPreference(KEY);
test.setEntries(testValues);
test.setEntryValues(testValues);
test.setValue(testValue[0]);
```