# How to set the Default Value of a ListPreference

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, preference, listpreference

i need to set the defult value for a ListPreference when the Activity starts.
I've tried with `ListPreference.setDefaultvalue("value");` but it makes the firts Entry of the List as default. I need it because i must check a condition and set as default the value which satisfies that condition, so I think it can't be done from the xml file (with `android:defaultValue`)

For example, suppose I have this array of values in the arrays.xml:

```
<string-array name="opts">
    <item>red</item>
    <item>green</item>
    <item>blue</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="opts_values">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

In the PreferenceScreen xml:

```
<ListPreference
    android:title="Colour select"
    android:summary="Select your favourite"
    android:key="colour"
    android:entries="@array/opts"
    android:entryValues="@array/opts_values" />
```

In the Activity I'd like to do something like this:

```
String mycolour;
if (something) {
    mycolour="1";
} else {
    mycolour="2";
}
ListPreference colour = (ListPreference) findPreference ("colour");
colour.setDefaultValue(mycolour);
```

But it doesn't work, because it makes the first choice as default. Could you explain me how to make another one as default? Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
setValueIndex(int index);
```

Comment: I am not sure this is the correct solution, since setValue or setValueIndex will effectively set the value, even if the user already has provided a custom value that is stored in the preferences. What works for me is 
`if (colour.getValue() == null) {
  colour.setValue(mycolour);
}`

Comment: and what is `int index`? What if I wanted to set a defined string?

Comment: How do i retrieve the last value stored in persistent storage for a preference who was set for persistent storage?

Comment: @AliBdeir the index is the index inside the value-list that should be used. But like having been noted it is not the solution itself. This should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 114):

You don't need to programmatically handle the default value of `ListPreferences`. You can do this in xml setting file. Below is an example

```
<string-array name="opts">
    <item>red</item>
    <item>green</item>
    <item>blue</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="opts_values">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

...

```
<ListPreference
    android:title="Colour select"
    android:summary="Select your favourite"
    android:key="colour"
    android:entries="@array/opts"
    android:entryValues="@array/opts_values"
    android:defaultValue="2" />
```

here I selected `2` as a default value. Remember `defaultvalue` will be `opts_values` element.

Comment: What if opts_values is an integer-array?  Or is that a bad idea?

Comment: Note that in XML, the first option starts at index 1 (i.e. `android:defaultValue="1"`) instead of 0.

Comment: @Keith if you use anything other than a `string-array`, you will get an error when it tries to find the corresponding item. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25355756/2550406

Comment: My xml file has the `app:` prefix on everything for some reason... Everything works except the `app:defaultValue` attribute

Comment: If your root element is androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen (or the support library equivalent) then you will need the `app:` prefix

Answer (score 13):

Sorry my bad English.

1. List item
2. Retrieve the list Check if the value is null. If it is null set to the default value.

**Code:**

```
ListPreference dataPref = (ListPreference) findPreference("keyList");

if(dataPref.getValue() == null){
    dataPref.setValueIndex(0); //set to index of your deafult value
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set your default value by using the key like this

```
<string-array name="syncFrequency">
    <item name="1">Block All Calls</item>
    <item name="2">Block Black List</item>
    <item name="3">Block Unknown Calls</item>
    <item name="4">Allow White List</item>
    <item name="5">Receive All Calls</item>
</string-array>




<string-array name="syncFrequencyValues">
    <item name="1">Block_All_Calls</item>
    <item name="2">Block_Black_List</item>
    <item name="3">Block_Unknown_Calls</item>
    <item name="4">Allow_White_List</item>
    <item name="5">Receive_All_Calls</item>
</string-array>



     <ListPreference
        android:key="prefSyncFrequency"
        android:entries="@array/syncFrequency"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:defaultValue="Block_Black_List"
        android:entryValues="@array/syncFrequencyValues"
        android:title="@string/call_block_options" />
```

Answer (score 3):

or you can also try `colour.setValue(mycolour);`

Answer (score 3):

**Just for the record if someone else has this problem:**

`setValueIndex(int X)` is setting the value @ index X to the default value - so **it is *probably* what you  are looking for**.

Set this value **AFTER** you added the Values! *(stupid mistake but took me half an hour)*

Answer (score 3):

```
((ListPreference) findPreference("pref_language")).setValue(Locale
                .getDefault().getLanguage());
```

`setValue()` is ListPreference's method, and `setDefaultvalue` is Preference's method

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's because the SharedPreferences will persist after you re-build the app.
Uninstall it and try again.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but here's another way to set the default value for `ListPreference` with the following line of code:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), R.xml.preferences, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the xml attribute `android:defaultValue="<VALUE>"` in your list tag to set the default value.

> Note: the `<VALUE>` is the actual value and not the index of string
>   array.

If still its not working, try below steps.

- Clear application data.
- Uninstall and reinstall the app
- Check the list preference, you will see the default value selected

Strange, I know but it worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Jetpack Preference, known as `androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1` in Kotlin, you can use:

`app:defaultValue="<Value_in_string-array_with_values>"`.

Additionally: `defaultValue` is not an index number, is the actual value from the values array.

I also recommend using a string resource for the default value and **clearing the data, uninstalling the app**, or removing the file:

- `<package_name_in_app_manifest>_preferences.xml` in `data/data/shared_prefs/<package_name_in_app_manifest>`. Replace `<package_name_in_app_manifest>` with real name like `com.example.yourapp`.

I was having the same issue and the `defaultValue` wasn't updating because it already had a wrong default value of "true". Solved it by using the Android Studio File Explorer and deleting the file.

And here is my solution example:

`res/xml/root_preferences.xml`

```xml
<ListPreference     
    app:key="mic"     
    app:title="@string/select_mic_title"  
    app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"    
    app:entries="@array/mic_entries" 
    app:entryValues="@array/mic_values"
    app:defaultValue="@string/default_mic"     />
```

`res/values/arrays`

```xml
<!-- Mic Preference --> 
<string-array name="mic_entries"> 
    <item>@string/default_mic</item> 
    <item>Headband</item> 
</string-array>  
<string-array name="mic_values">
     <item>@string/default_mic</item> 
    <item>Headband</item>
 </string-array>
```

`res/strings.xml`

```xml
<string name="default_mic">Integrated</string>
```

Result:
[Setting Fragment with default list value of "Integrated" given by string resource @string/default_mic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otihY.jpg)