# ListPreference summary not formatting

Tags: android, preferences, listpreference

I have a ListPreference and I want to show the current entry in the summary. According to the [docs for ListPreference.getSummary()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#getSummary%28%29), I'm supposed to be able to do this by including `%s` in the summary string. Unfortunately, the activity just displays the `%s` in the summary.

The XML is pretty standard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListPreference
        android:key="displayMode"
        android:summary="@string/display_mode_summary"
        android:title="@string/display_mode"
        android:defaultValue="BOTH"
        android:entries="@array/displayModes"
        android:entryValues="@array/displayModeValues"
        />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The value of the string `display_mode_summary` is just `%s`. (The value `"BOTH"` is present in the `displayModeValues` array.) If I subclass ListPreference like this:

```
public final class DisplayModePreference extends ListPreference {
    // ...

    @Override
    public CharSequence getSummary() {
        return String.format(super.getSummary().toString(), getEntry());
    }
}
```

then when the preferences activity starts, the current value is correctly interpolated into the summary. But when I click on the preference and select a different value from the dialog, when the dialog closes the summary still shows the now-old value. I need to close the preferences activity and restart it to see the change.

I've tried this in several emulators at different API levels. What do I need to so that the displayed summary always reflects the current value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override "onDialogClosed" as below:

```
@override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

    if (positiveResult) {
        setSummary(getEntry());
    }
}
```

This will set the summary of your preference to the text of the selected entry.

Comment: I ended up restructuring my preferences (for other reasons) so ListPreference wasn't used at all. If I had needed ListPreference, I probably would have ended up using this. It seems kind of silly that a ListPreference doesn't automatically update its summary after it displays its list.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But my CustomListPreference always sends `positiveResult = false` and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

The original `getSummary()` in ListPreference only works when `getEntries()`, `getEntryValues()` and `defaultValue` are pre-populated when the Preference screen loads. So it works fine when you use a static fixed list of items, like a `<string-array>` resource.

But if you are dynamically generating the `entries` and `entryValues` at runtime, you need to ensure that these lists are generated when the Preference screen loads in `onCreate()` and also [ensure that the `defaultValue` is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197228/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-listpreference). Something like this:

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("dynamiclistItems");

    CharSequence[] entryDisplayNames = new CharSequence[3];
    entryDisplayNames[0] = "Item A";
    entryDisplayNames[1] = "Item B";
    entryDisplayNames[2] = "Item C";

    CharSequence[] entryValues = new CharSequence[3];
    entryValues[0] = "Item A Value";
    entryValues[1] = "Item B Value";
    entryValues[2] = "Item C Value";

    listPreference.setEntries(entryDisplayNames);
    listPreference.setEntryValues(entryValues);

    if (listPreference.getValue() == null ||
         listPreference.getValue().equals("")) {
        // There is no stored string in shared prefs.
        // The user has not chosen any value. So make
        // the summary display a default entry "Item A"
        // display name, which is item 0 in the 'entries' list. Info:
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197228/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-listpreference
        listPreference.setValueIndex(0);
    }
}
```

For static lists that are populated with `<string-array>`, just ensure that `android:defaultValue="..."` is defined, and that it points to a valid item in the 'values' array. For example: `android:defaultValue="Item A Value"`

This will ensure that the `android:summary="%s"` will work properly for dynamically generated and static lists.

Comment: This is interesting. However, it doesn't explain the problem I was originally having, because the entries and entry values were being declared as references to `<string-array>` resources in the preferences xml. They weren't being generated dynamically.

Comment: For static lists, just ensure that `android:defaultValue="..."` is defined, and that it points to a valid item in the 'values' array. You may also need to call `listPreference.notifyChanged();` to force the summary to update itself, when an item is clicked.

Comment: That call to `notifyChanged()` was probably the issue. As my original post shows, I already had `android:defaultValue` set in the xml.