# List preference showing selected value in summary

Tags: java, android, android-2.3-gingerbread, listpreference

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823442/android-list-preferences-have-summary-as-selected-value) it works like a charm. Application's minSdkVersion is 14, but now I have to provide support for sdkVersion 9 (Android 2.3.3 Gingerbread). The solution does not work for API Level 9. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#setSummary(java.lang.CharSequence)) also recommends using '%s'. Is there any nice way of handling it in older/legacy version of android. Here is my ListPreference code.

```
<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="option_1"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/options_dialog_title"
    android:entries="@array/option_entries"
    android:entryValues="@array/options_values"
    android:key="algo"
    android:title="@string/pref_title"
    android:summary="%s"/>
```

The output appears like this.

[image]

I am looking for something nice and easy. There exist a lengthy way of doing it by getting the preference.

```
Preference prefListOption = (Preference)findPreference("algo");
```

and calling setSummary function something like this

```
prefListOption.setSummary(value);//user selected value
```

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738586/listpreference-summary-not-formatting