# Android set default value of ListPrefrence dynamically created and filled

Tags: android, android-preferences, listpreference

I need to set default value for the ListPreference that is created dynamically. It's dynamically created because it's a preference for camera focus modes and each device can have different set of focus modes. `listPreferenceFocusMode.setDefaultValue(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);` does not work, or [How to set the Default Value of a ListPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197228/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-listpreference?rq=1) accepted answer in this link does not work, and it' is not right because it overrides user's selection.

```
    // Preview Focus Mode
    int indexContinuous = 0;
    if (focusModes != null && focusModes.size() > 0) {
        entries = new String[focusModes.size()];
        entryValues = new String[focusModes.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < focusModes.size(); i++) {
            entryValues[i] = entries[i] = focusModes.get(i);
            if (entryValues[i].equals(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
                indexContinuous = i;
            }
        }

        listPreferenceFocusMode.setEntries(entries);
        listPreferenceFocusMode.setEntryValues(entryValues);

        if (listPreferenceFocusMode.getValue() == null) {
            listPreferenceFocusMode.setValueIndex(indexContinuous);
        }
        if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
            listPreferenceFocusMode.setDefaultValue(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        } else {
              listPreferenceFocusMode.setDefaultValue(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        }
    } else {
        listPreferenceFocusMode.setEnabled(false);
        listPreferenceFocusMode.setSummary("Focus Modes are not supported");
    }
```

I tried setting defaultValue or getting value using `listPreferenceFocusMode.getValue()` but it does not work also because `listPreferenceFocusMode.getValue()` is not `null`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a boolean flag to check that if it's the first start of the application. If it is, set `listPreferenceFocusMode.setValueIndex(indexContinuous);` and set true and save isFirstStart flag to sharedPrefrerences to  invoke setValueIndex method only once. It would be better if `listPrefrence` remembered it's dynamic default value but it does not.